# what are the steps to add new angular component npm install & import?

Tags: angular

what are the steps to add new angular component?

1. `npm install`
2. import
   gives an error when added into HTML
   for example:

```
npm i --save @angular/material/tree'
```

in the .TS module

```
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree'
```

3. in the html

   ```
   <mat-tree>
      <mat-nested-tree-node>
        parent node
        <mat-nested-tree-node> -- child node1 </mat-nested-tree-node>
        <mat-nested-tree-node> -- child node2 </mat-nested-tree-node>
      </mat-nested-tree-node>
   </mat-tree>
   ```

It gives error mat-tree-node is NOT a known element

Comment: You need to import `MatTreeModule` in app.module or any feature module which is using <mat-nested-tree-nod>

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation first? The documentation for a popular library like Material is usually fairly thorough, and I'd be surprised if they didn't have instructions for you to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Use
npm i @angular/material

And then
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree'

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a specific module as you did here :

```
npm i --save @angular/material/tree'
```

Using NPM you can add a full library to your project, to add Angular Material Library to your project you should follow the steps here, it also explains how to add a component to your module https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Steps :

1. run `ng add @angular/material`
2. Import the Material module you want to use in your module

```
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
…
@NgModule ({....
  imports: [...,
  MatTreeModule,
…]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular Material you have to do an import in the app.module.ts file. Along with putting it under "imports".

I recommend checking out this page: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started